# How to control the size of the select box in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, ruby-on-rails-3

I create the select box like this:

```
f.select(:my_select_name, options_for_select(...))
```

How could I control the size (width) of the select box ?

For input text field I do:

```
f.text_field(:field_name, :size => my_size)
```

but for "select" it doesn't work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic synatx for select is

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Options are replace by the dropdown option values and
you can replace the html_options for the width.

eg. `<% select("company", "branch_id", Branch.all.collect {|b| [ b.name, b.id ] }, { :prompt => "Select" }, {:class => "companySelect" })`

For select_tag you can use

```
select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})
```

Here the option is similar to html_options of select.

eg. `<%= select_tag 'company_name', options_for_select(get_company_name), :class => "select1"%>`

For more details please see [select Tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)
 and [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)

Comment: Hi! Where can I see all the available options for `html_options` and `options` ?

Comment: The commonly used html_options are  :multiple - allow multiple choices, :disabled - disable the input,  :size - set the size,  :class - define the class, :onclick - calls javascript onclick and  other key creates standard HTML attributes. 
 For the options you can check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how to set the size of the select box. `:size` does not work for `select` (only for text fields). Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: If you provide the option size for a select box it will take that as a vertical size, for width you can use <%= select_tag 'company_name', options_for_select(get_company_name), :class => "select1"%> and providing width to the class select1 in the css or you can use <%= select_tag 'company_name', options_for_select(get_company_name), :style => 'width: 500px;'%>

Answer (score 16):

In gist, I use:

```
<%= f.select(:my_select_name, [1,2,3,4,5], {}, :style => "width:70px") %>
```

Or if I am using something like Twitter Bootstrap, I use a class:

```
<%= f.select(:my_select_name, [1,2,3,4,5], {}, :class => "col-md-1") %>
```

Comment: Thanks, so work for me. You can also do like this `<%= f.select(:foo_id, Foo.all.collect{|foo| [foo.name, foo.id,]}, {}, :style => "width:250px")`